# Using Responsive-nav.js with Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, responsiveness

Utilizing [responsive-nav.js](http://responsive-nav.com/) I am attempting to create a responsive navigation. I've used responsive-nav.js on non-angular projects in the past without any issue. I am having difficult figuring out how to include required code. For example, I attempted to place this line of code in my index.html file before the closing body tag  as instructed on in the [documentation](http://responsive-nav.com/).

```
<!-- Put this right before the </body> closing tag -->
<script>
  var nav = responsiveNav(".nav-collapse");
</script>
```

The script above console gives me an error "responsiveNa is not defined".

I created a directive for responsive-nav.js but this did not resolve the problem.

```
.directive('responsiveNav', function(){
    return{
        restrict: 'E',

        link:function(scope, element, attrs){

            $(element).responsiveNav("foo",{
                customToggle  : "nav-toggle",
                navClass      : "nav-collapse"


            });
                    Scope.$apply();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: You can't have `$(element).$apply()` inside the options object for the plugin at first. Another thing is, The order of paramerts is wrong. The link function takes `scope, element, attrs` but you've specified it in wrong order.

Comment: @mohamedrias I've removed $(element).$apply( ) from inside the options object for the plugin, should i move this outside the options object or is this line of code not required? I've also put the params in the correct order scope, element, attrs

Comment: You must have `scope.$apply()` instead of `$(element).$apply(). Yes, move it outside

Comment: @mohamedrias everything is in place but it's still not working